# I have already plotted a function now I would like to delete two coordinates and group the ylabel with his value then put the origine O(0,0)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,french]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{sexdts}{rgb}{0.1803921568627451,0.49019607843137253,0.19607843137254902}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm, scale=.78]
\begin{axis}[
x=20cm,y=100cm,
xlabel = {t(s)} ,
ylabel = {x(m)},
title = ,
axis lines=center,
ymajorgrids=true,
xmajorgrids=true,
xmin=0,
xmax=0.9,
ymin=-0.06307777777777772,
ymax= 0.06307777777777772,
xtick={0,0.1,...,1.7},
ytick={-0.06,-0.049999999999999996,...,0.049999999999999996},]
\clip(-0.1475960421205511,-0.06307777777777772) rectangle (1.7742928467683272,0.053744444444444484);
\draw[line width=3pt,color=sexdts,smooth,samples=100,domain=0:1] plot(\x,{0.04*sin((5*3.141592653589793*(\x)+(7*3.141592653589793)/6)*180/pi)});
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw[color=sexdts] (-0.13346450617283875,0.039355555555555595) node {$f$};
\end{scriptsize}
% \node[below left ] at (0,0) {O};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: function]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me guess: you used some software to produce this plot? If you add

```
ytick scale label code/.code={},
/pgf/number format/precision=1,
/pgf/number format/fixed
```

to the options of the axis, you get

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,french]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{sexdts}{rgb}{0.1803921568627451,0.49019607843137253,0.19607843137254902}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm, scale=.78]
\begin{axis}[
x=20cm,y=100cm,
xlabel = {$t$(s)} ,
ylabel = {$x$(m)},
title = ,
axis lines=center,
ymajorgrids=true,
xmajorgrids=true,
xmin=0,
xmax=0.9,
ymin=-0.06307777777777772,
ymax= 0.06307777777777772,
xtick={0,0.1,...,1.7},
ytick={-0.06,-0.049999999999999996,...,0.049999999999999996},
ytick scale label code/.code={},
/pgf/number format/precision=1,
/pgf/number format/fixed]
\clip(-0.1475960421205511,-0.06307777777777772) rectangle (1.7742928467683272,0.053744444444444484);
\draw[line width=3pt,color=sexdts,smooth,samples=100,domain=0:1] plot(\x,{0.04*sin((5*3.141592653589793*(\x)+(7*3.141592653589793)/6)*180/pi)});
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw[color=sexdts] (-0.13346450617283875,0.039355555555555595) node {$f$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, this is still unfortunate in many ways. It would be much better to just use `pgfplots` without external programs to plot this function.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{sexdts}{rgb}{0.1803921568627451,0.49019607843137253,0.19607843137254902}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45]
\begin{axis}[width=.95\textwidth,
xlabel = {$t$(s)} ,
ylabel = {$x$(m)},
title = ,
axis lines=center,
ymajorgrids=true,
xmajorgrids=true,
xmin=0,
xmax=0.9,
ymin=-0.063,
ymax= 0.063,
xtick={0,0.1,...,1.7},
ytick={-0.06,-0.05,...,0.05},
/pgf/number format/precision=3,
/pgf/number format/fixed,scaled y ticks=false]
\addplot[line width=3pt,color=sexdts,smooth,samples=100,domain=0:1] 
{0.04*sin((5*pi*x+(7*pi)/6)*180/pi)} node[pos=0.9,above]{$f$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are genius @Schrôdinger's cat, this is what I want. You're right I use Geogebra first as software then try change it after. Could you point out to me great and easy resources to learn pgfplots?  Because I plot a lot of functions.

Comment: @OusseynouDiagne You're welcome. The pgfplots manual is very good, I think.

Comment: Thank you, in the last solution, inside the addplot command why did you put times 180/pi ?

Comment: @OusseynouDiagne The `180/pi` is already present in your code. What I did was to replace `3.141592653589793` by `pi`.

Comment: Oh okay, I understood.